# Read Only property for input field

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

The thing that I'd like to happen is that when the value of the **status field** is ***Paid*** the input field *fines* should be read-only.
How to achieve this?

This is my form:

[image: This the form look like]

This is my code:

```
   <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Status</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="status" value = "Paid" name="status"  readonly>
              </div>
                    
                </div>


             
             <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fines" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Fines</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" 
                               class="form-control" id="fines"  name="fines"   required>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Javascript line of code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready (function(){
$('input[type=text][name=status]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == "Paid") {
        $("#fines").prop("readonly",true);
    }
    else{
        $("#fines").prop("readonly",false);
    }
});
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: The "status" field is also readonly, so how are you expecting any "change" event to ever occur on it? It will not happen because the user cannot modify the field value. When exactly do you want the readonly setting to be applied? Should it be immediately when the form is loaded into the browser, or at some later time?

Comment: Your point is that when you change the field from editable to read-only there must be an action to the status field?

Comment: No that wasn't my point at all. I was asking _you_ what the trigger should be in order to make the change? Because at the moment the code you've written doesn't really make sense - it will never trigger (due to the reason I mentioned in the first comment)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you're status field is set to readonly on load, I'd imagine you want to trigger a change event instantly.

```js
$(document).ready (function(){

  // setup a variable for multi-use
  var $statusField = $('input[type=text][name=status]');

  // watch for changes to the statusField
  $statusField.change(function() {
    
      // simpler check for paid status
      $('#fines').prop('readonly', this.value === 'Paid');
  });
  
  // trigger a change on ready
  $statusField.change();
 
});
```

This way you have access to trigger the change programatically but also have the ability to watch the status field. I've also cleaned up your code a little bit!

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
if ($(this).val() == "Paid") {
            $("#fines").attr("readonly",true);
        }
        else{
            $("#fines").attr("readonly",false);
        }
```